# Get events without running modal

Tags: python

I want to handle some gui updates myself and use

`app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(myFunction)`

with this code

```
def myFunction(context):
  if bpy.context.scene.is_updated:
    if myPropertyChanged():
      print(bpy.context.scene.myProperty)
```

It works flawless, except that I can't detect when I stop dragging a slider value (= mouseUp). The problem is that Blender returns values *while* dragging an input. While draggin an input x from 0 to 100, Blender returns multiple values like "1,23,24,38,49,99,100".
I just want the value when a) the user stops dragging completely or b) the user stops clicking (mouseUp). I the returned values in between 1 and 100 are from Blender guessing wrong that the user stopped dragging.
A hacky way would be to measure time and then decide "oh nothing is changing anymore" but that could conflict with a user inputing value very fast with the keyboard.

**I don't want to use a modal operator for this.** Is there a way of getting a mouseUp-event without a modal operator?

Comment: It actually doesn't have to be a mouse up EVENT, it would be enough if I could just check the state of the left mouse button (PRESSED, NOT PRESSED / RELEASED) myself.

Comment: I think modal operator is the only way to get events, the `event.type` will tell you `LEFT_MOUSE` while the `event.value` will tell you `PRESS` `RELEASE`