# Modal operator from different context

Tags: python, operator

I've asked a very similar question yesterday, but I have a more concrete example here. I'm using the template "Operator Modal View3d Raycast" with some modifications:

```
class ViewOperatorRayCast(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "view3d.modal_operator_raycast"
    bl_label = "RayCast View Operator"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        
        if context.space_data.type != 'VIEW_3D': # This doesn't work           
            return {'PASS_THROUGH'} # This doesn't work
        
        if event.type == 'RIGHTMOUSE' and event.value == 'PRESS': # The operator only does any thing for RMB
            main(context, event) # This is where the raycasting goes on. See the template                           
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        
        elif event.type in {'ESC'}:
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'} # I want the operator to keep going

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if context.space_data.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        else:
            self.report({'WARNING'}, "Active space must be a View3d")            
            return {'CANCELLED'}

    def Execute(self, context)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

I can start the operator fine by pressing F3:

[image: Invoking the modal operator]

But I would like to start the operator from python. I have tried by adding the execute method, but this doesn't work since the context is either the text editor or console (not the view3d). I got the idea of using execute here (top link), but he just mentions the problem with context and not the resolution - if any:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8S-s7tuTdY    (about 15:30)
[Constantly running modal operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28999/constantly-running-modal-operator) (also have some of what I seek)

Is it possible to trick Blender to think that I called the operator from view3d or something like that?

Comment: You can right-click the yt video and select "Copy video URL at current time": https://youtu.be/A8S-s7tuTdY?t=904

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html?highlight=invoke_default#execution-context -> TLDR; By default the execute method will be called, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73548/31447 (helped me a lot a few years ago). To answer your question you should add *how* do you want to call it... "I want to call it with python" not pretty useful TBH.

Comment: Take out the conditional?  See "overriding context"

Comment: @ brockmann. I missed the documentation you linked. Looks like what I need. Thanks. I want to call the operator from a script like this: bpy.ops.view3d.modal_operator_raycast() which calles the execute method, but from a wrong context (the text editor).

Comment: See the second code snippet in the docs. Also I'd recommend add any relevant information to your q since others may not read the comments.

Comment: Answered your question from yesterday. Of opinion this is a dupe of that, or may as well be.

Comment: @batFINGER it is basically the same, but I didn't see your an answer ???, so I though that I ought to make it a more concrete with the template raycast operator. I'll look at your answer. Thanks!

Comment: In future recommend editing original question over asking pretty much the  same question as a new question on the next day.